# Can doctrine2 hydrate a new entity from an array?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I think the title asks it all. Very simple, I have an entity:

```
class User {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $username;
}
```

with all the appropriate setters and getter. I have an array:

```
array( 'name' => 'joe', 'username' => 'shmoe' );
```

and I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Some\Unknown\Doctrine\Object::hydrateFromArray($array);
```

Obviously creating a function to hydrate it an object would be easy enough, but surely doctrine must have something build in to accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Figured it out.
Given a repository:

```
//for odm
$repo->getDocumentManager()->getHydratorFactory()->hydrate($entity, $array);
```

I don't know if the same can be done for ORM, but I'm currently using ODM.

Comment: Looks like its MongoDB?

Comment: This works only for Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Hydrator\HydratorInterface. Not for all database types.

Comment: Can you please post the whole code for this? I can't find the DocumentManager. Who is the $repo on your answer? 
`$repo = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\OrdemServico');
                $retorno = $repo-> getHydratorFactory()->hydrate('Application\Entity\OrdemServico', $ordemServico);`
This doesn't work...

Answer (score 5):

You could use the Serializer Component:

```
$user = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'Namespace\User', 'json');
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object

Comment: The symfony serialize component doesn't support deserialization of json. However, the JMS serializer does.

Comment: What makes you think the Symfony serializer component doesn't support json? I am using it all the time to deserialze json and would always recommend using the symfony serializer component over jms - which is partly abandoned. Here is a great post of how flexible the Symfony serializer is: http://thomas.jarrand.fr/blog/serialization/

Answer (score 1):

As with Entities it's up to you to create the setters and getters.

```
class User
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $username;

    public function fromArray($array)
    {
         // Code to fill the object here.
    }
}
```

Also there's nothing that says you can't implement it in the constructor either. Remember, Doctrine 2 entities don't inherit anything from a main class unless you do it yourself. It just acts on it.

Comment: What if you have a relation in your entity? How would you escape the injection of the EM in your entity? (in order to get the related object/objects, you will need the EM)

Comment: Hydratation logic (which is related to infra, since it is basically a mapping to/from database) should not be located an entity (which is domain and must not know anything about its persistence)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer of HKandulla, i using symfony component `ObjectNormalizer`:

```
$myHydratedObject = (new ObjectNormalizer())->denormalize($array, MyAnyEntity::class);
```